# Item does not decrease Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I want to make a feature, that if I click quantity decrease by 1 but it does not decrease and only returns HttpResponse.

```
class CartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "shop/cart.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cart'] = Cart.objects.annotate(
        price=Sum(F('orderitem__item__price') * F('orderitem__quantity'))
        ).get(order_user= self.request.user)
        cart = context['cart']
        cart.total = cart.price
        cart.save()
        context['order_items'] = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)
        return context
    def post(self, request):
        if 'minus' in request.POST:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(order_user=self.request.user)
            primary = request.POST.get('orderitem__id')
            item = OrderItem.objects.filter(id=primary, cart=cart)
            item.quantity = F('quantity') - 1
            item.update()
            return HttpResponse("cart uptaded")
```

Answer (score 2):

Item is a `QuerySet`, you do not update a queryset by altering an attribute: you use the parameters in the [**`.update(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) for that:

```
OrderItem.objects.filter(id=primary, cart=cart).update(
    quantity=F('quantity')-1
)
```

Comment: It returns HttpResponse but it still does not decrease items number. There is problem with matching i mean with "id" field.

Comment: @Kay; then likely `primary` is `None` (so you did not send an `orderitem__id` in the POST request. It thus looks like there is probably a *misnomen* in the HTML form.

Comment: Yeah exactly primary is none sir

Comment: @Kay: well that means that your HTML form has no `<input name="orderitem__id" ...>`

Comment: Oh exactly, but it is not what I want, i would like to decrease number without providing primary key in input field.

Comment: @Kay: well then you will need to pass it through the URL. You need the id of the item to decrease so it should be passed through the HTTP request header, the URL, or cookies (although that looks very ugly), but the primary key needs to be passed. Especially since HTTP is a stateless protocol.